# How to install coprocessor to Hbase?

Tags: hbase

I am learning about Hbase and coprocessor. And the documentation shows that the coprocessor jar needs to be in hbase classpath. Does it mean if I want to add a my custom coprocessor I have to restart hbase? Will data be lost if I restart hbase?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the jar with coprocessor to hdfs:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
fs.copyFromLocalFile(localFile, hdfsFile);
fs.close();
```

Then you need to add the coprocessor to existing table(or create new table):

```
HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
HTableDescriptor descriptor = admin.getTableDescriptor(tableName);
descriptor.addCoprocessor(MyCoprocessor.class.getName(), hdfsFile,
        Coprocessor.PRIORITY_USER, null);
admin.modifyTable(tableName, descriptor);
admin.close();
```

If you want to do this as a specific user all the code should be inside the:

```
UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hbase");
ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void run() throws Exception {
        // HERE
        return null;
    }
});
```